# What are most beautiful Silverlight charts?

Tags: .net, silverlight, charts

We need most handsome Silverlight controls now. It is very important for us to have sexy animated charts.

Please, advise.

[Here is one we found.](http://www.visifire.com/silverlight_charts_gallery.php)

EDIT: Sorry being lazy while creating this question. Please do not close it. To be more clear I'll list all our needs.

We need **speedometer-like chart, World-map chart**, bar-chart, line-chart.

EDIT2: I lookup all the Internet to find World map silverlight chart and did not succeeded. Have any body saw this one?

EDIT3: RESULT: All charts we need including world map chart found here: http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Map/FirstLook Thank you people.

Comment: As money does not matter, I can build a bar graph with a 1px image, but will be really expensive. =)

Comment: What does it means "Community wiki please" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **[telerik chart controls for silverlight](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/FirstLook)**

Comment: Found world map chart here http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Map/FirstLook ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Telerik's controls](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/) are very widely used, but as mentioned in your question [Visifire's controls](http://www.visifire.com/silverlight_charts_gallery.php) are very impressive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for paid ones then http://www.dundas.com/Components/Gallery/Flash/Chart/ is a good option.

Comment: yes. has silverlight support also http://www.dundas.com/Components/Products/Chart/NET/Features/NewFeatures.aspx

Comment: http://www.dundas.com/Components/Products/Chart/NET/Demos/index.aspx

Comment: Thank you. These are not sexy at all (comparing to Telerik and Visifire.